# Why is RPM not finding my package version, even though it lists it as available?

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild

I am creating RPMs from spec files. I was installing java8 latest rev as a dependency, and it always worked fine. Today I needed to pin the java8 version down to a specific rev, but I'm getting an error. What I have changed in the spec file was from:

```
Requires:   java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

to

```
Requires:   java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel = 1:1.8.0.252.b09
```

You can see the version `1:1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10` is available, so why do I get this error?

```
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10 for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64
---> Package libXfont.x86_64 0:1.5.1-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXft.x86_64 0:2.3.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libXt.x86_64 0:1.1.4-6.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libfontenc.x86_64 0:1.1.2-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libthai.x86_64 0:0.1.12-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package pixman.x86_64 0:0.32.8-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
           Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el6_9.x86_64 (centos_base)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.171-8.b10.el6_9
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.181-3.b13.el6_10
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.191.b12-0.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.191.b12-0.el6_10
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-1.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.201.b09-1.el6_10
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.212.b04-0.el6_10
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.222.b10-0.el6_10
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.232.b09-1.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.232.b09-1.el6_10
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.242.b07-1.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.242.b07-1.el6_10
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.262.b10-0.el6_10
           Installing: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.265.b01-0.el6_10.x86_64 (centos_updates)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.265.b01-0.el6_10
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you edit your question to include the full command you typed which led to this error message?

Comment: The `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64` requires `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10`. The `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10` is not available in the repositories you are using. (was deleted, or for other reasons)